# Referencing DE Fields Not Working

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, dataextensions

I've got a triggered send which adds values to a data extension. the data extension then feeds into a journey which sends emails. each email has the following code:

```
%%[

VAR @futureDate, @today, @formattedDate, @timestamp, @subLanguage, @result, @url_yes
SET @today = Now(1) 
SET @timestamp = Format(@today, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
SET @futureDate = DateAdd(@today, 27, 'D')
SET @formattedDate = Format(@futureDate,'yyyy-MM-dd')

Set @subLanguage= RetrieveSalesforceObjects('MAG_Subscription__c', 'MAG_Language__c', 'Id', '=', 'SubscriptionID')

set @url_yes = Concat('https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/0tifupaskin?sk=','SubscriptionID','&ln=',@subLanguage,'&expiry=',@formattedDate)

SET @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('MAG_Subscription__c','SubscriptionID','MAG_VerifiedRequestDate__c', @timestamp)

]%%
```

the value that i want to reference is called SubscriptionID but it doesn't seem to work. I thought that because the DE is feeding the journey i have access to its data or do I need to call it in some way. Currently, the email doesn't send because something is wrong with the code.

Thanks as always for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Should've use AttributeValue.

```
 <!--%%[

VAR @futureDate, @today, @formattedDate, @timestamp, @subLanguage, @result, @url_yes, @subID, @rowCount, @subscriptionRow, @subscription
SET @today = Now(1) 
SET @timestamp = Format(@today, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
SET @futureDate = DateAdd(@today, 27, 'd')
SET @formattedDate = Format(@futureDate,'yyyy-MM-dd')

SET @subID = AttributeValue('SubscriptionID')

SET @subscription = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('MAG_Subscription__c', 'MAG_Language__c', 'Id', '=', @subID)
SET @rowCount = rowCount(@subscription)
IF @rowCount > 0 THEN
    SET @subscriptionRow = Row(@subscription, 1)
    SET @subLanguage = FIELD(@subscriptionRow, 'MAG_Language__c')

ENDIF

SET @url_yes = Concat('https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/0tifupaskin?sk=',@subID,'&ln=',@subLanguage,'&expiry=',@formattedDate)

SET @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('MAG_Subscription__c',@subID,'MAG_VerifiedRequestDate__c', @timestamp)

]%%-->
```